# PHP Getting a script together which will send a newsletter to all emails in database

Tags: php, mysql, email, newsletter

I have got a database with some emails (max 300) and I want to be able to send an newsletter/email to those, the email/newsletter is written in text a form which on submit takes the action through to sendemails.php, but how do I get sendemails.php to send the input of that textarea to send it to all the emails in the database?

Comment: `mail($to, 'Here is some spam', $_POST['textareafield']);`

Comment: I will have to have something like

$email = "SELECT email FROM member";

$to = $email;

but then the emails wont be divided via commas?

Comment: @MarcB +1 "here is some spam" lol...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM member");
$emails = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    $emails[] = $row[0];

$to = implode(", ", $emails);

mail($to, "subject", $_POST["myTextarea"]);
```